# C++/Qt изменение внешнего вида заголовка окна

Tags: c++, qt, gui, ui

Задался вопросом изменить внешний вид `UI` в проекте `QtWidget`.

Разобрался с `QSS`, однако остался нерешённым вопрос изменения внешнего вида заголовка окна (там, где пишется название, а также расположены кнопки закрыть/свернуть/etc).

Нарыл информацию, что нужно изначально скрыть стандартный заголовок. Нашёл, как это сделать - нужно просто добавить флаг:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
w.show();
```

После скрытия, нужно подключить вместо окна свой заголовок (отдельный ui интерфейс) и связать его действия со стандартными кнопками. И вот по этой теме я просто абсолютно ничего не могу найти, никакого намёка на средства реализации и т.д.

Возможно кто-нибудь сможет помочь или же делал это у себя в проекте и сможет поделиться здесь.
Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: пожалуйста, приведите ссылку откуда информацию нарыли

Comment: Хорошо бы описать чего Вы хотите достичь, на каких системах будет работать Ваша прожка. А то, вдруг, Вы просто "хотите странного" :)

Answer (score 1):

Почитатайте ответ на подобный вопрос с [аглицкой части](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507864/how-to-customize-the-title-bar-of-a-qt-app-through-qt-stylesheet), самый последний.
Ну и можете погуглить "qt  customize window title bar"

А так, нужно просто понимать несколько концепций интерфейса Qt

1. Title bar, строго говоря, нельзя кастомизировать, только отключить
2. Layouts. На любой виджет можно натянуть некий Layout, накидать в него еще виджетов, и так далее. Есть определенные правила по установке размеров виджетов внутри layout
3. Сигналы и слоты
4. Формы, что создаются при помощи дизайнера, видимые как ui, суть xml, который парсится в ui_somename.h Стоит открыть несколько, чтобы понять что магии нет и как все устроено.

Вкратце

1. Отключаете встроенный title, с этим вы справились.
2. На MainWindow используете подходящий layout. (Если Вы работаете в QtCreator, просто киньте на MainWindow обычный виджет, щелкните в MainWindow и выберите вверху подходящий layout. Например Vertical Layout. Если все правильно, виджет займет весь доступный рамер)
3. Делаете свой виджет, взамен title bar, вручную или в QtCreator как форму, наследуя от QWidget
4. В конструкторе MainWindow создаете экземпляр и закидываете его наверх layout MainWindow
5. Настраиваете сигналы от вашего title bar куда нужно

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле к таким выводам я пришёл, просмотрев несколько листингов, которые получил от одного человека.
Приведу отрывки, чтобы было понятнее.
Заголовок класса:

```
#include "ttwidget.h"
#include <QDir>

namespace Ui {
class MenuBar;
}

class MenuBar : public TTWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void SetTitle(const QString Title) const;
    explicit MenuBar(TTWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MenuBar();

signals:
    void Minimized_Window();
    void Close_Window();

private:
    void Set_Textures();
    void Set_Connections();
    Ui::MenuBar *ui;
};
```

Далее у нужно создать отдельный ui и подключить вот так:

```
MenuBarW = new MenuBar();
ui->MenuBar->layout()->addWidget(MenuBarW);
connect(MenuBarW, SIGNAL(Close_Window()), this, SLOT(close()));
connect(MenuBarW, SIGNAL(Minimized_Window()), this, SLOT(Minimized_Window()));
```

Также есть класс TTWidget, от которого наследуется класс MenuBar'а, однако как раз в нём у меня вылетела куча ошибок, которые я увы исправить не смог. Решил разобраться с тем, что делается вообще в этих исходниках и попробовать собрать нужную информацию уже по кусочкам.
На всякий случай, хедер TTWidget:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGraphicsDropShadowEffect>

class TTWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    virtual void Set_Connections() = 0;
    virtual void Set_Textures() = 0;
    void CreateShadow(QWidget *Widget, unsigned short XOffSet, unsigned short YOffSet, unsigned short int radius,unsigned short int acolor) const;
    explicit TTWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать завернуть изначальный UI используя [паттерн Декоратор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80_.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0_C.2B.2B).
В новом UI описать поведение заголовка окна и вместо стандартного UI подключить уже созданный вами класс-обертку UI [(как подключать)](http://www.prog.org.ru/topic_9561_0.html).